# Creating index for a Json attribute stored in a JSONb column which contains array of json in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, jsonb

I am using postgres from past few days and i came up with requirement which i am trying to find solution.

I am using postgres sql.
I have a Table which is like this

```
CREATE TABLE location (id location_Id, details jsonb);

INSERT INTO location (id,details)
VALUES (1,'[{"Slno" : 1, "value" : "Bangalore"},
             {"Slno" : 2, "value" : "Delhi"}]');

INSERT INTO location (id,details)
VALUES (2,'[{"Slno" : 5, "value" : "Chennai"}]');
```

From the above queries you can see that a **jsonb column with name details
is present which has an array of json as value stored.**
The data is stored like this because of some requirement.

**Here i want to create an index for the Slno property present in jsonb

  column values.**

Can someone help me out in finding  solution for this as it would be
 very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is not an index for a single JSON property, rather for the whole attribute, but you can use it to perform a search like you want:

```
CREATE INDEX locind ON location USING GIN (details jsonb_path_ops);
```

If you need the index for other operations except `@>` (contains), omit the `jsonb_path_ops`. This will make the index larger and slower.

Now you can search for the property using the index:

```
EXPLAIN (VERBOSE) SELECT id FROM location WHERE details @> '[{"Slno" : 1}]';

                               QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on laurenz.location  (cost=8.00..12.01 rows=1 width=4)
   Output: id
   Recheck Cond: (location.details @> '[{"Slno": 1}]'::jsonb)
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on locind  (cost=0.00..8.00 rows=1 width=0)
         Index Cond: (location.details @> '[{"Slno": 1}]'::jsonb)
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you for posting.
My doubt is can't an index be created for SlNo property alone.

Comment: I mean creating index for Slno attribute.

Comment: No, but what is lacking in the index I described?

Comment: I have a specific requirement to create index in the way i have mentioned above that is why i was asking.